# Apple sign error: auth/invalid-credential React Native using Expo Managed Workflow with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to implement sign in with Apple using Expo managed workflow with firebase, but I got this error:

> Error: [auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
import { AppleButton,appleAuth } from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';
```

```
  async function onAppleButtonPress() {
    const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
      requestedOperation:appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
      requestedScopes:[appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME,appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL],
    })

    const { identityToken, nonce } = appleAuthRequestResponse;
    console.log(identityToken);
    console.log(nonce);

    const appleCredential = auth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(identityToken, nonce)
    console.log(appleCredential);

    return auth().signInWithCredential(appleCredential);
  }

        {isAppleLoginAvailable && 
        <AppleButton
        buttonStyle={AppleButton.Style.BLACK}
        buttonType={AppleButton.Type.SIGN_IN}
        style={{
          width: 250,
          height: 45,
        }}
        onPress={() => onAppleButtonPress().then(() => console.log('Apple sign-in complete!')).catch((e) => console.log(e))}
      />}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
My Services ID was set up like:
App ID Prefix.Bundle ID

But it turns out it should be only your bundle ID.
Now works

Comment: What is "My Services ID"?

Comment: In Firebase Authentication, under sign-in method there is a field: "Services ID (not required for Apple)"